# WordPress Admin Bar Not Displaying Both Custom Drop-down Menus

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm having trouble displaying two custom drop-down menus in the WP admin bar. What I want is the first drop-down to display the back-end (editing part) links of every page and the other to display the front-end links of every page. Right now, only the last foreach statement being called displays. Any suggestions are much appreciated.

```
function admin_bar_link($admin_bar) {

    if ( !is_super_admin() || !is_admin_bar_showing() )
    return;

$pages = get_pages();
$nurs = get_site_url();

$admin_bar->add_menu(array(
    'id' => 'this',
    'title' => __($nurs),
    'href' => $nurs
));

$admin_bar->add_menu(array(
    'id' => 'edit_pages_links',
    'title' => __('Edit Pages'),
    'href' => false
));

$admin_bar->add_menu(array(
    'id' => 'view_pages_links',
    'title' => __('View Pages'),
    'href' => false
));     

foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
    $title = $page->post_title;
    $url = get_permalink ( $page->ID )  . 'wp-admin/post.php?post=' . $page->ID . '&action=edit'; //edit post url   

         $admin_bar->add_menu (array( 
        'title' => $title,
        'href' => $url,
        'parent' => 'edit_pages_links'
        )
    );

}//end foreach  

foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
    $title = $page->post_title;
    $url = get_permalink ( $page->ID ) . '?p='. $page->ID;

        $admin_bar->add_menu ( array (
            'title' => $title,
            'href' => $url,
            'parent' => 'view_pages_links'
            )
        );                          
 }//end foreach 

}
add_action('admin_bar_menu', 'admin_bar_link');
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly your function should accept the $admin_bar variable like this:
`function admin_bar_link($admin_bar)`

and you don't need `global $wp_admin_bar` anymore. Then replace these:

```
$wp_admin_bar->add_menu
```

with this

```
$admin_bar->add_menu
```

Then the menus should appear on the admin bar.

Comment: Just tried your suggestion but, unfortunately, still same result.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the last function being called works?